# Get current learning rate when using ReduceLROnPlateau

Tags: python, pytorch, learning-rate

I am using [`ReduceLROnPlateau`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau.html) to modify the learning rate during training of a PyTorch mode. `ReduceLROnPlateau` [does not inherit from `LRScheduler`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py#L913) and does not implement the `get_last_lr` method which is PyTorch's recommended way of getting the current learning rate when using a learning rate scheduler.

**How can I get the learning rate when using `ReduceLROnPlateau`?**

Currently I am doing the following but am not sure if this is rigorous and correct:

```py
lr = optimizer.state_dict()["param_groups"][0]["lr"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can skip the `state_dict` of the optimizer and access the learning rate directly:

```py
optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"]
```